# Navegar entre archivos html guardados en la memoria de android

Tags: html, android-studio, web, webview

Estaba creando una aplicación que contiene un webView que ocupa la pantalla entera. El webView carga una página que tiene botones, y al pulsarlos me redirecciona a otra página html que tengo en la memoria del teléfono.

En andoid 4.4 funciona perfectamente, pero luego quise probarla con android 9 y la aplicación se cierra, osea no funciona. Alguna idea de porque sucede esto.

Los botones que inserto en la página inicial son de este tipo:

```
<button onclick="location.href='pagina2.html'">carga página 2</button>
```

y los archivos html estan todos en la misma carpeta

Answer (score 0):

Ok ya lo conseguí. No se que versiones de android no permiten navegar entre páginas sin añadir webclient, android 8 y 9 no dejan navegar sin webclient así que añadí esta linea en mi archivo java donde creo el webView:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Al hacer esto, ya me permite navegar entre archivos html en cualquier versión de android.

fin.

Comment: Te recomiendo que, aunque en este caso no te de reputación extra, marques las respuestas a tus preguntas como "aceptadas" (clicka en el *check* que aparece al lado). De ese modo las preguntas aparecen marcadas como *respondidas*